# Not able to configure Play 2.2 app with Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, playframework, playframework-2.0

I'm trying to set up a play 2.2 application using hibernate, but it doesn't seem to be workin. I think i have all the correct files, but when i load up my application, the tables aren't auto generated like when using EBEAN. Here are my files:

conf/META-INF/persistence.xml

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
             version="2.0">

    <persistence-unit name="defaultPersistenceUnit" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <non-jta-data-source>DefaultDS</non-jta-data-source>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

build.sbt

```
name := "listr"

version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"


libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  javaJdbc,
  javaEbean,
  cache,
  javaJpa,
  "org.hibernate" % "hibernate-core" % "4.2.3.Final",
  "org.hibernate" % "hibernate-entitymanager" % "4.2.3.Final"
)     

val appDependencies = Seq(
  javaJdbc
)

play.Project.playJavaSettings
```

conf/application.conf

```
# Database configuration
# ~~~~~
# You can declare as many datasources as you want.
# By convention, the default datasource is named `default`
#
db.default.driver=org.h2.Driver
db.default.url="jdbc:h2:mem:play"
# db.default.user=sa
# db.default.password=""
db.default.jndiName=DefaultDS
jpa.default=defaultPersistenceUnit
```

after changing the various files to the ones mentioned above, i made a simple  model to test if it was setup correctly and if hibernate would auto generate the table, but nothing seemed to happen

apps/models/List.java

```
package models;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;


@Entity
public class List {
    @Id
    private long id;
    private String name;

}
```

After creating this model, i ran the project and after loading it checked the h2 database and none of the tables had been created and evolution script had been created. Is there something else i need to do/do i need to manually create the evolutions scripts? i thought it would be auto created like with E-Bean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing `hbm2ddl` property in your `persistance.xml`:

```
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
```

Possible values are: `create`, `update`, `create-drop`, `validate`. More [details here](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en-US/html/session-configuration.html#configuration-optional).

Answer (score 0):

Remove "Resource local" from your persistence.xml In case of container managed environment we don't use resource local .By default its use JTA Transaction . so you can remove "Resource local " and leave it.